# How to use command name with spaces?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How to make bot works when there is a space between commands in python bot. I know we can do that using sub-command or `on_message` but is there any another option to do that for only selected commands not for all commands.

The following code will not work.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def mobile phones(ctx):
    msg = "Pong. {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

So I tried using alias but still it won't working.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['mobile phones'])
async def phones(ctx):
    msg = "Pong. {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible.  I'm pretty sure that the parsing to figure out which command you're trying to call splits the input before considering the commands.  What you can do is just puts a `if message.content.startswith('!mobile phones')` in your `on_message` event. Possibly you could even invoke the command from there too, but I'm not sure how that would work.

Answer (score 6):

Strictly to say, you can't. Since discord.py's command names ends with space, as defined in views.py. There are, however, a few options: re write how discord.py views handle messages (I wouldn't recommend this), use `on_message` and `message.content.startswith`, or use groups.

Since `on_message` is fairly straight forward to use, I will instead show you how you can "hack" the `group` syntax to allow command name with spaces.

```
class chain_command:
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        names = name.split()
        self.last = names[-1]
        self.names = iter(names[:-1])
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    @staticmethod
    async def null():
        return

    def __call__(self, func):
        from functools import reduce
        return reduce(lambda x, y: x.group(y)(self.null), self.names, bot.group(next(self.names))(self.null)).command(self.last, **self.kwargs)(func)

@chain_command("mobile phones", pass_context=True)
async def mobile_phones(ctx):
    msg = "Pong. {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

In discord:

```
me: <prefix>mobile phones
bot: Pong. @me
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a less complicated way of doing this, but you could pass args as the command name itself! So in your example `mobile phones` you could use an arg over it.

```
@client.command
async def mobile(ctx, phones = None)
  if phones != "phones":
    return
  await ctx.send("Yay it works")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is outdated I understand, but if you have a command group, subcommand group, then a slash command you can have spaces in your commands when they are entered in [discord](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command%20group#discord.ext.commands.Group).