# How do you create aliases with spaces in discord py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been using discord py and I wanted a command to be called when someone writes in 'No u'. The one problem is, I can't make it work since there is a space in it. I've tried to use the escape code, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Hi! Please make sure to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as part of your question so that we can better help you out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't *simply* create aliases with spaces using command decorators. The long answer is that you [can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51005832/7808223) with some extra code.

You could however use the `on_message` event, which isn't recommended for commands, but will suffice:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message) # add this if you're also using cmd decorators
    if message.content.lower().startswith("no u") and not message.author.bot:
        await message.channel.send("No! You!")
```

---

**References:**

- [`on_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message)
- [`Bot.process_commands()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)
- [Letting spaces work with decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51005832/7808223) - bit convoluted, but it gets the job done

Comment: I have one problem with this: Whenever I type in "No u", my discord bot spams me until I turn it off.

Comment: You'll want to check that the author isn't a bot, otherwise it'll be triggered by itself. I'll edit my answer to account for that ^