# Spaces in a @ client.command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I make a space in my command that is no longer useitem but use item?

Because at the moment it looks very unprovesional to enter such a command

```
@client.command()
async def use20items (ctx):
    Pflanzen= await ctx.send ('**test**')
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await Pflanzen.edit(content='message')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use command name with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999489/how-to-use-command-name-with-spaces)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the name of the command in the decorator:

```py
@client.command(name="use item")
async def ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add spaces using aliases like the example below:

```py
@client.command(aliases=["use item"])
async def use_item(ctx):
    ...
```

I can see that you have a space between `use20items` and `(ctx)`, and the `ctx.send` and `('**test**')` you might end up getting an error by doing that.
I hope this helped.